# How do I make my application startable from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, ppa, scripts, deb, make

I've created several Python applications wherefore I know how to create a DEB and how to push an application into my PPA in Launchpad. What I never found out is how to make the application startable from the terminal by just entering its name like you use to do with any other Linux application. I guess that I have to create a link to the application's shell script in /usr/bin/ but I don't know how to do this in my rules file which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_install:
    dh_install nota/* /usr/share/nota/
    dh_install applications/nota.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frist your script has to be executable so:

```
chmod +x script.py
```

Then you have to either include the script directory in the user's `PATH` variable (source it in the .bashrc)

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/script"
```

or copy/link it in a directory that already listed in `PATH`:

```
cp script.py /usr/bin/
```

That should do it in the make file. For the last option make has to be invoked with `sudo`.

Comment: Make sure to strip the `.py` though. Commands should not have extensions.

Comment: Okay somehow I overlooked the `.deb` building part an just thought of a make file. I have no experience with that. My bad. Still why can't you just put `ln -s /path/to/script.sh /usr/bin/commandname` in your rule-file?

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected. I prefer to create a link to my 'script.sh' in /usr/bin/. But I still don't know how to do it.